# How to revert particular commit in between for a single file with multiple commits

Tags: git

Let us say I have a file

**Hello.txt**

```
1. Hello
2. World
```

I add in the following text (`3. Bye`)..so the file becomes

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. Bye
```

And Commit it to `SHA1_1`

Again add another line(`4. World`)

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. Bye
4. World
```

and commit it to `SHA1_2`

If I revert the `SHA1_1` should I not just get a file like this(remove the `3. Bye` that I added in `SHA1_1`)

```
1. Hello
2. World
4. World
```

Doesn't work that way. So I tried to reset to the original `SHA1_1` and cherry-picked `SHA1_2`. Guess what? `SHA1_2` has the snapshot with entire file with `3. Bye` which was not on that commit. Is there a better way to get just the difference as we see in diff between those commits?

@JDB I must be doing some thing wrong...I said

```
revert bye_commit

1. Hello
2. World
<<<<<<< HEAD
3. Bye
Z. Extra Line
4. World
=======
Z. Extra Line
>>>>>>> parent of f6e1e81... Added Bye
```

Comment: What do you mean "Doesn't work that way"? As long as the merge can happen cleanly (unlikely in this simplified example), it _should_ work that way. What happens instead?

Comment: what about merges...this is simple commit by commit situation and when you revert a in between commit ..it doesn't remove the lines it brought in that commit...

Comment: What do you mean by commiting to SHA1_1 and SHA1_2?

Comment: I just had to give a name to the regular SHA1... just had to refer it back..The situation is simple...can we give just the changes from a commit applied/do a surgical recovery of the content we commit in each commit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that with your example there's no way to get around a conflict, which means a simple revert is going to require you to resolve that conflict. Your changes are too close together, so Git can't confidently tell them apart.

If we modify the example slightly by separating the changes introduced by SHA1_1 and SHA2_1, then we can do this without a conflict:

**Added Hello.txt**

```
1. Hello
2. World
Z. Extra Line
```

**SHA1_1**

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. Bye
Z. Extra Line
```

**SHA2_1**

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. Bye
Z. Extra Line
4. World
```

Now Git can confidently identify that 3 and 4 are separate changes and do the auto-merge for you.

```
> git revert SHA1_1
```

produces a new commit that looks like this:

```
1. Hello
2. World
Z. Extra Line
4. World
```

You can see an example of these commits here: https://github.com/cyborgx37/sandbox/commits/SO-47100683

---

#### More Depth

In your example, when you revert `SHA1_1`, it's trying to restore the file to:

```
1. Hello
2. World
```

When it compares the current state of your file, `SHA2_1`, it sees:

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. Bye
4. World
```

so git doesn't know what to do about lines 3 and 4.

In my modified example, the revert attempts to apply `SHA1_1'`:

```
1. Hello
2. World
Z. Extra Line
```

and the current state of the file is `SHA2_1'`:

```
1. Hello
2. World
Z. Extra Line
4. World
```

Git can compare the Z line and see that a line was removed and automatically merge the two changes together.

Comment: I added a new line at the end of z.Extra Line and it started...looking at it..thanks